# SpringBoot 1.5.1 uses snapshot sub dependencies?

Tags: spring-boot

I just started using SpringBoot 1.5.1. When I select the spring-cloud related dependencies from the Spring Initilzr and make a build for my application, I end up with SNAPSHOT dependencies for the following, among others

spring-cloud-aws-dependencies
spring-cloud-bus-dependencies
spring-cloud-commons
spring-cloud-config-server
spring-cloud-consul

Is this correct? My companies MAVEN repo does not allow SNAPSHOT files to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Initilzr prefers the Dalston snapshot release of spring-cloud to the current stable Camdem.SR5 release.

Just update your POM file and replace `Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` with `Camden.SR5` for the `spring-cloud-dependencies` dependency management.